# wishy-washy (what is wishy?) (can't find the meaning of 'wishy')

Tags: word-meaning

> wishy-washy

What's wishy? (Can't find the meaning of 'wishy')

'washy'means 'overdiluted, watery, or weak'

Comment: What is "washy", for that matter?

Comment: Just need to know the meaning or definition of 'wishy'.

Comment: Why do you need to know "wishy" but not "washy"? Either way, neither has any meaning outside the expression "wishy-washy".

Answer (score 5):

This is a slang term formed by [reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication). Similar examples include

> chit-chat, clip-clop, ding-dong, flimflam, mishmash, ping-pong, and zig-zag

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wishy-washy) suggests this definition:

> lacking in firm ideas, principles, or the ability to make a decision:

Clearly, **wishy-washy** is derived from the meaning of **washy** that you quote in your question. If you **lack *firm* principles,** it is because—figuratively speaking—your principles are **overdiluted** or **weak**.